# Meaning of Intel processor suffixes

Tags: cpu

I just bought a Core i7 second generation machine which shows the processor in the BIOS as:

> Intel Core i7-2620M CPU @ 2.70Ghz

I have seen i7 3rd and 4th generation processors on Google but I don't understand the suffix (i.e. what is meant by **M**). I have also seen other processors with suffixes like **MQ* and **QX**.

What do these suffixes mean?

Comment: I'd note this does change with time. On desktop there's K series, S series and so on

Answer (score 81, accepted):

#### What do the suffixes mean?

- `C` - Desktop Processor based on the LGA 1150 package with high performance graphics
- `D` - Meaning is unknown as of Dec 2016
- `E` - Embedded (the processor can be utilized in embedded systems)
- `H` - High performance graphics
- `K` - Unlocked
- `M` - Mobile
- `P` - Processor without integrated graphics controller

  Note: Back in the Core 2 days, a P-series chipset didn’t include an integrated GPU. Now, P-series chips just include slower integrated GPUs.
- `Q` - Quad-core
- `R` - Desktop processor based on BGA1364 (mobile) package with high performance graphics
- `S` - Performance-optimized lifestyle
- `T` - Power-optimized lifestyle
- `U` - Ultra-low power
- `X` - Extreme edition
- `Y` - Extremely low power

---

#### Which has the best performance?

See the [Performance Benchmark Library](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/library/benchmarks.html).

> This library is a tool that can help you find performance benchmarks for Intel® products. Select at least one of the filter options below and click Get Results to find the benchmark you’re looking for.

---

#### Which has the best power consumption?

The detailed specifications of each processor can be found at [View processor specifications and compare processors](http://ark.intel.com/#@Processors).

---

#### About Intel® Processor Numbers

> The processor number is one of several factors, along with processor
> brand, specific system configurations, and system-level benchmarks, to
> be considered when choosing the right processor for your computing
> needs.
>
> A higher number within a processor class or family generally indicates
> more features, but it may be more of one and less of another. Once you
> decide on a specific processor brand and type, compare processor
> numbers to verify the processor includes the features you are looking
> for.

Source [Intel® Processor Numbers: Laptop, Desktop, and Mobile Device](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html)

---

#### Additional Sources

- [Decoding Intel’s Laptop Processor List [Technology Explained]](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/decoding-intels-laptop-processor-list-technology-explained/)
- [Intel launches new desktop and mobile CPUs](http://www.cpu-world.com/news_2015/2015122701_Intel_launches_new_desktop_and_mobile_CPUs.html)
- [Intel has new chips with some odd model numbers](https://www.slashgear.com/intel-has-new-chips-with-some-odd-model-numbers-29420107/)

Comment: @DetlevCM That link is **already in my answer** - "See the following link for all the Letter and Product Line suffixes. Source Intel® Processor Numbers: Laptop, Desktop, and Mobile Device" -> target is http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html