# 2 in 1 laptops with quad core processors

Tags: laptop, compatibility, specifications

I'm searching through laptops for a laptop with a hinge screen (something like Lenovo yoga or Asus flip).

I can't find any with a quad-core processor! They all come with a U processor.

Is there a reason for this? Would a HQ processor in a hybrid laptop be meaningless somehow? Or is it just to save power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Or is it just to save power?

Yes, it is to save power. The Intel Processor `U` suffix stands for "Ultra-low power"

See my answer [Meaning of Intel Processor suffixes](https://superuser.com/a/940176/337631) for more information on how to compare processors for performance and power consumption.

Note also this [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/940168/meaning-of-intel-processor-suffixes/940176#comment1278712_940176) by [misha256](https://superuser.com/users/319310/misha256) on the above answer:

> A high spec mobile CPU can outperform a low spec desktop CPU no problem so the suffixes don't help you there. Likewise I've seen mobile CPUs that can burn through more watts than a low/mid range desktop CPU.

---

#### What do the suffixes mean?

- `C` - Desktop Processor based on the LGA 1150 package with high performance graphics
- `H` - High performance graphics
- `K` - Unlocked
- `M` - Mobile
- `Q` - Quad-core
- `R` - Desktop processor based on BGA1364 (mobile) package with high performance graphics
- `S` - Performance-optimized lifestyle
- `T` - Power-optimized lifestyle
- `U` - Ultra-low power
- `X` - Extreme edition
- `Y` - Extremely low power

#### About Intel® Processor Numbers

> The processor number is one of several factors, along with processor
>   brand, specific system configurations, and system-level benchmarks, to
>   be considered when choosing the right processor for your computing
>   needs.
>
> A higher number within a processor class or family generally indicates
>   more features, but it may be more of one and less of another. Once you
>   decide on a specific processor brand and type, compare processor
>   numbers to verify the processor includes the features you are looking
>   for.

See the following link for all the `Letter` and `Product Line` suffixes.

Source [Intel® Processor Numbers: Laptop, Desktop, and Mobile Device](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe it's to reduce power consumption, because that gives better battery life (or just lets them make the battery smaller and lighter) and also reduces the cooling needs.  2-in-1s need to be thin and light to be practical in tablet mode, so manufacturers don't want to have to shove a bunch of batteries, fans, and radiators into them.