# What does the P at the end of the I3-6098P means?

Tags: cpu, desktop-computer, computer-building, intel-core-i3

I have been looking around the internet for the meaning of intel processor suffixes, but so far I haven't been able to identify what the P at the of the core I3-6098P means. This is probably the first time I have ever seen the P suffix. Could some one help me identify its meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What is the meaning of the Intel Processor `P` Suffix?

`P` used to mean a (Core 2) processor without an integrated GPU.

It was later redifined to to mean a processor with a slower integrated GPU.

> `P` - Processor without integrated graphics controller.

Source [Intel processor numbers (model numbers) of desktop CPUs](http://www.cpu-world.com/info/Intel/processor-number.html)

> P-series: Back in the Core 2 days, a P-series chipset didn’t include an integrated GPU. Now, P-series chips just include slower integrated GPUs.

Source [Pentium? Core i5? Core i7? Making sense of Intel’s convoluted CPU lineup](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/02/pentium-core-i5-core-i7-making-sense-of-intels-convoluted-cpu-lineup/)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Meaning of Intel Processor suffixes](https://superuser.com/a/940176/337631)

Comment: @guest hence the quoted comment that says "Now, P-series chips just include slower integrated GPUs."

Comment: @Mokubai: [i3-6098P](http://ark.intel.com/products/93366/Intel-Core-i3-6098P-Processor-3M-Cache-3_60-GHz) has **HD 510** while [i3-6100](http://ark.intel.com/products/90729/Intel-Core-i3-6100-Processor-3M-Cache-3_70-GHz) has **HD 530**, which indeed is stronger iGPU. (I was baffled with "Processor without integrated graphics controller".)

Comment: @guest I have clarified the answer.

Comment: Sorted it out finally: Back in Core 2, GPU is not yet integrated into the CPU, it is in the chipset, eg. G31/G33/G45. P35/P45 has no iGPU. This is what "P-series chipset didn't include an integrated GPU" is referring to. i5-2380P/i5-2450P/i5-3350P have no iGPU. i3-6098P/i5-6402P have slower GT1. ==== Honestly I would say there is no consistent meaning with the suffix P. i5-2550K has no iGPU neither, why isn't it named i5-2550PK?