# Meaning of "DU" suffix in intel's cpu

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i5

I see an Intel CPU with code "Intel Core i5 6198 DU".

Two questions:

- what it means DU suffix? ("U" is usually for low power, but "D" is unknown to me).
- Differences with "i5 6200 U" ?

Answer (score 3):

#### What is the DU suffix?

This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

> At this time, we do not have information on what feature is associated with the letter "D" in the model number.

Source [Intel launches new desktop and mobile CPUs](http://www.cpu-world.com/news_2015/2015122701_Intel_launches_new_desktop_and_mobile_CPUs.html)

> The remaining four chips are the completely newcomers to the family, the mobile Core i5-5200DU, i5-6198DU, Core i7-5500DU, and i7-6498DU. Intel has reserved the “U” suffix for its ultra low power chips. How that differs from “DU” is still unknown at this point. In terms of specs, however, the four seem to have the same cores and L3 cache as their regular “U” counterparts.

Source [Intel has new chips with some odd model numbers](https://www.slashgear.com/intel-has-new-chips-with-some-odd-model-numbers-29420107/)

---

#### What are the differences between the i5 6198 DU and the i5 6200 U?

The differences are the lines with the lilac background.

[image]

...

[image]

---

[image]

Source [Intel Core i5-6198DU vs i5-6200U](http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/931/Intel_Core_i5_Mobile_i5-6198DU_vs_Intel_Core_i5_Mobile_i5-6200U.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Meaning of Intel processor suffixes](https://superuser.com/a/940176/337631)