# What does the "TE" suffix in the Intel Core i3-6100TE's name stand for?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i3, components

[This page](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html) on Intel's website says that the "T" suffix represents a "Power-optimized lifestyle", which, as far as I understand, means better power efficiency, but doesn't say anything about the "E" suffix (except for the older Core 2 processors, where it seems to have a similar meaning to the current generation "T").

The i3-6100T and i3-6100E also exist, both with a TDP of 35W, just like the i3-6100TE. The main differences i can see while [comparing them](http://ark.intel.com/compare/90611,90734,88181) on Intel's website are that the two processors with the "E" have:

- a lower clock speed (2.7 GHz vs 3.2 GHz)
- something called "**E**mbedded options available" (maybe this is it?)

So does anybody know what the "E" means?

Comment: @Xavierjazz I don't think it's spam.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything.  It's just a model number.  If Intel indicates the `T` means "Power-optimized lifestyle" and `E` is connected to "Embedded" CPUs then a `TE` would be an `embeddded power optimized` product.

Comment: [Exact;y](http://ark.intel.com/compare/90734,90611,88181) the case ^^.  doesn't matter what the `E` stands for literally, a `TE` product, is the combined product line of both `T` and `E`.  Contact a Intel sales associate if you really want to know because its likely only they would know.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Why does it look like like spam?

Comment: @donut - In the past users, have submitted similar type questions, in an attempt to submit spam as an answer to those questions they submitted.

Comment: @Xavierjazz This question is thorough and worded way too well to tingle my spammy-senses.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### What is the meaning of the Intel processor `E` suffix?

> The E suffix is one you’ll see on a few products, but as a consumer you don’t particularly need to worry about. The letter stands for embedded, with means the processor can be utilized in embedded systems.

Source [Decoding Intel’s Laptop Processor List [Technology Explained]](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/decoding-intels-laptop-processor-list-technology-explained/)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Meaning of Intel processor suffixes](https://superuser.com/a/940176/337631)